# looking for a science fiction book. About an artifact found in space

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm looking for a science fiction book about an artifact found in space that had the remains of an alien inside with the tech to bring him back to life. He turned out to be a dictator with psychic powers who was taking over the earth. The hero of the story finds the dictator's enemies home world where he has 3 alien organs implanted in his body to give him the same powers so he can fight the dictator.

Comment: If it weren't for the last sentence, it would be _[World of Ptavvs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ptavvs)_ by Larry Niven.